# Covariance and inner products

Tags: probability

In the wikipedia section on [covariance & inner products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Relationship_to_inner_products)

It states that "$\sigma^2(X) = \sigma(X, X) \ge 0$ for all random variables $X$, and $\sigma(X, X) = 0$ implies that $X$ is a constant random variable $(K)$."

Is it true that $X$ is constant here or almost surely constant (I can only see almost surely here)? If the latter then is this no longer a inner product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost surely constant.

Random variables that are equal almost everywhere are identified. So the inner product space really consists of equivalence classes of random variables. Two random variables are equivalent if they are equal almost everywhere.

By the way "almost surely" is probability speak for "almost everywhere."

Answer (score 1):

It is almost surely constant. ${}\qquad{}$